# How do I duplicate Apple Configurator profiles?

Tags: ios, apple-configurator

I've been working with Apple Configurator in its various versions (now 1.2.1) since its introduction and it is a powerful tool to manage and supervise iPads & other iOS devices.

One glaring omission is the inability to duplicate an existing profile in order to make small changes and save as a new profile. Without this function, one must create a new profile and recreate all the settings. With complicated profiles this becomes a tedious and potentially error-prone exercise. One cannot simply export the profile, rename the file in the Finder and re-import: it merely replaces the original because the original profile's name is coded into the XML, and I can't figure out what to change in the XML code to get this working, if that is indeed what must be done.

The iPhone Configuration Utility (latest v3.5) has the function I need, but it cannot process new iOS 6 configuration details and strips them out when imported.

Has anybody figured out how to duplicate profiles?

Comment: I hope someone has figured it out, but with the way things are signed and architected, I'm guessing we have no good solution at present other than to re-do the work in the GUI.

Comment: Where can this XML file be found? I'm looking in com.apple.configurator but there's nothing that looks like a profile file.

Comment: @Dreyfuzz If you export the file to your desktop (or some other convient location) you can then copy it and follow the instructions from there.

Comment: I don't see an export option for profiles in v2.3 (only for 'docs and info')?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it.

Open the XML file in TextEdit (or some other XML editor of your choice).

Scroll to the very bottom.

Look for:
        PayloadDisplayName
    Orig Profile
    PayloadIdentifier
    orig.profile

Change these two instances Orig to Dup or some other unique name.
Save file.
Go to configurator > import > point to file - it imports as 'dup profile' with all other settings in tact.

(I suppose you could also make XX copies of the XML file and edit each one, but it is easier just to leave the file open in TextEdit, make a change, save, import, make a change, save, import, lather, rinse, repeat.)

Comment: It's worth noting that if you export the file from Configurator you DO NOT want to sign it, otherwise it won't sign it in UTF-8 and some editors may have problems interpreting the XML file.